# Is there a way to alter a type using type_traits within a template parameter list?

Tags: c++11, templates, generic-programming

```
template
<
    template <typename, typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename _Tp = storage::unknown_type,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type
>
struct Example_Buffer:
    public Buffer<storage_t, _Tp, is_allocated> { ... };
```

In this code, I want to remove the reference, if `_Tp` has one. I do not want to use `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference_v<_Tp>>`, because I do want the program to compile if `_Tp` is a reference, but I would like to remove it in that case. I thought of a solution, but it did not seem ideal:

```
template
<
   template <typename, typename, typename>
        class storage_t,
    typename _Tp = storage::unknown_type,
    typename is_allocated = std::false_type,
    typename _Tp2 = std::remove_reference_t<_Tp>
>
struct Example_Buffer { ... };
```

EDIT: It does not seem ideal, because it feels like type `_Tp2` is unnecessary and could be avoided. I may be wrong; if so, please tell me.

Is there a better way to do this? Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

EDIT: I actually forgot to mention the current solution:

```
struct Example_Buffer
    : public Buffer<storage_t, std::remove_reference_t<_Tp>, is_allocated { ... };
```

However, I may want to use `_Tp` within `Example_Buffer` struct, so this is not ideal either.

Comment: "I thought of a solution, but it did not seem ideal" - why `std::remove_reference` not seems ideal?

Comment: I thought it would be preferable to avoid creating the extra type, using only three types. If this extra type is not really relevant regarding performance or cannot be avoided, please let me know, because I'm rather uncertain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to use both types, `_Tp` and the no-reference-`_Tp`; I don't know how you can do this without creating (implicitly or explicitly) an extra type.